# Audio playing issue on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, createjs

I am developing a game where in I have number of audio file to be loaded before the actual game start.
I have 60 to 90 audio files. I load them and play one by one. The loading functionality is through CreaJS Lib. The audios are playing fine on Chrome and Mozilla successfully. But I have issue on IE9.

How we can preload audios and run them one by one on IE9.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Any one can update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has some limitations to the number of audio files that can be loaded/played. Try reducing the manifest to 30 or so audio items, and see if it helps.

We have also had some really weird issues where audio encoded with certain settings doesn't work in IE - so perhaps re-encode some of your files to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the 90 audio files, and make one audio file that includes all 90 clips.

You only play one at a time, so just jump to and play to the spot that represents the audio file.

http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

Play at exactly 35 seconds in the song

```
audioElement.currentTime=35;
audioElement.play();
```

you then pause it with a timeout.  To make it clean, make sure you add a few seconds of time between each clip, so that if the timeout is a little late, it still does not play the next clip